# Does firestore support acid transactions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Looking into firebase for running a "serverless" app, was curious to know how much of ACID does firestore support? there documentation has some information on transactions only but nothing more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cloud Firestore supports multi-document ACID transactions. ACID in that the transactions are:

- Atomic: All or none of the document mutations are applied
- Consistent: No transaction will leave the DB in an inconsistent state
- Isolated: Strict serializability, just like Google's Cloud Spanner
- Durable: It's synchronously replicated across regions.

Comment: So multiple people writing the same document is not ACID?